# how to read and write data in NFC tag (Card: NTag-213, Reader: ACR122) using c#

Tags: c#, nfc

I need to write custom program in c# for reading and writing NFC Tag, Iam using Ntag-213 card and ACR122 nfc reader device.

The main issue is in writing data to nfc tag.

I have tried this for writing:

```
public bool WriteBlock(String Text, String Block)
{

    char[] tmpStr = Text.ToArray();
    int indx;
    if (AuthBlock(Block))
    {
        ClearBuffers();
        SendBuff[0] = 0xFF; // CLA 
        SendBuff[1] = 0xD6;// INS
        SendBuff[2] = 0x00;// P1                           // P1
        SendBuff[3] = (byte)int.Parse(Block);           // P2 : Starting Block No.
        SendBuff[4] = (byte)int.Parse("16");            // P3 : Data length

        for (indx = 0; indx <= (tmpStr).Length - 1; indx++)
        {
            SendBuff[indx + 5] = (byte)tmpStr[indx];
        }


        SendLen = SendBuff[4] + 5;
        RecvLen = 0x02;

        retCode = SendAPDUandDisplay(2);


        if (retCode != Card.SCARD_S_SUCCESS)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: _"The main issue is in writing data to nfc tag"_ But **what** issue are you encountering? An exception? If so, on which line?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at CLA, INS is definitely wrong.

Refer example of Ultralight write in [ACR122's manual](https://www.acs.com.hk/download-manual/1083/API-ACR122USAM-2.01.pdf) 
It works for NTAG as well.

Step 3) Update the content of Page 04h with the data “AA BB CC DDh”.
(Tx) FF 00 00 00 09 D4 40 01 A2 04 AA BB CC DDh
(Rx) 61 05h
(Tx) FF C0 00 00 05h
(Rx) D5 41 [00] 90 00h
Or
Step 3) Write (Mifare compatible Write) the content of Page 04h with the data “AA BB CC DDh”.
(Tx) FF 00 00 00 15 D4 40 01 A0 04 AA BB CC DD 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00h
(Rx) 61 05h
(Tx) FF C0 00 00 05h
(Rx) D5 41 [00] 90 00h
Tip: This command is implemented to accommodate the established Mifare 1K/4K infrastructure. We
have to assemble the data into a 16 bytes frame. The first 4 bytes are the data to be written in the
page while the rest of the bytes (12 ZEROS) are for padding. Only the block 4 (4 bytes) is updated
even though 16 bytes are sent to the reader.